# What is the difference between tf.square, tf.math.square and tf.keras.backend.square?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I have been looking to learn TensorFlow and I have noticed that different functions are used for the same goal. To square a variable for instance, I have seen `tf.square()`, `tf.math.square()` and `tf.keras.backend.square()`. This is the same for most math operations. Are all these the same or is there any difference?

Answer (score 3):

Mathematically, they should produce the same result. However Tensorflow functions in `tensorflow.math.somefunction` are used for operating Tensorflow tensors.

For example, when you write a custom loss or metric, the inputs and outputs should be Tensorflow tensors. So that Tensorflow knows how to take gradients of the functions. You can also use `tf.keras.backend.*` functions for custom loss etc.

Try to use `tensorflow.math.somefunctions` whenever you can, native operations are preferred. Because they are officially documented and guarateed to have backward compatibility between TF versions like TF 1.x and TF 2.x.